# mac os x equivaliant of append dns suffixes in windows

Tags: mac-osx

Trying to append dns suffixes in mac os x. In windows all I do is go to the advance adapter properties and select the Append these DNS suffixes (in order) and add the suffix domain.com and I can then ssh with just the server name without having to type the fully qualified domain name. I would love to know what the mac version of this is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this off topic? It's definitely related to networking and it just saved me a lot of time. Please reconsider this choice.

Answer (score 5):

Search domains is what it is called for the Mac.

see: http://support.apple.com/kb/ph6373